# Получить значение SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml

Достаю из объекта значание:

`$articulCurrent = $tovary -> Товар[$x] -> Артикул;`.

При печати выдаёт цифру, всё корректно.

Но при передаче в функцию

`merchView($tovary, $priceArray);`.

выдаёт ошибку: `Illegal offset type`.

`print_r($articulCurrent);` выдаёт: `SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 000529 )`

Как преобразовать этот объект, чтобы передать число в функцию.

Comment: Мне кажется вам нужно извлечь данные из объекта используя какой-то метод, что нибудь типа `->attributes()` почитайте  [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.simplexmlelement.php).

Comment: если вам нужно число, то приведите объект к `int`

Comment: @teran, помогает, только срезаются передние нули у артикулов. Приведение к (string) подходит лучше, артикул передаётся полностью.

Comment: echo current($articulCurrent); // 000529